# Pi Camera LED blinking

Tags: camera, led

I have gotten back to using my Model B Revision 2.0 Pi.  After starting it up, I noticed the red LED on the camera is blinking (not the Pi itself, that one is solid).  When I take a picture, the camera's LED goes solid for a time, but then it gets right back to blinking.  I have been trying to find documentation on its behavior without much success.  Could anyone point me to the relevant source, or tell me what the camera's LED means when it is blinking?  I am not interested in disabling the LED at this time.

Comment: Is it a Chinese fake camera? They don't behave in the same way as the genuine Raspberry Pi Foundation cameras.

Answer (score 1):

For those whom it may concern -- found out the issue.  Forever ago I had configured a program to run on startup that continually takes a picture.  Took a look at `top`, found it, killed it, and the camera light is now off.